# VB write ´╗┐ | ́╗┐'java is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: java, vb.net, batch-file

I have created a programm... this programm need to write in a .bat file

This is the code

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("C:\Server\Minecraft\Start.bat",
    "java -Xincgc -XX:PermSize=128m -Xmx" + TextBox1.Text + "m -Xms" + TextBox1.Text + "m -jar " + TextBox3.Text + " nogui", True)
```

But the result when i start the "Start.bat" file is: 
́╗┐'java is not recognized as an internal or external command

How i resolve this problem?

Thanks bye

Comment: Can you give us actual contents of .bat file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably writing the file in such a way that there is a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the start of the file. Batch files cannot have a BOM at the start. You will have to find out how to write a file without including a BOM.